# Grep find lines that have 4,5,6,7 and 9 in zip code column

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I'm using grep to display all lines that have ONLY 4,5,6,7 and 9 in the zipcode column.

How do i display only the lines of the file that contain the numbers 4,5,6,7 and 9 in the zipcode field?

A sample row is:

15 m jagger         mick            41 4th 95115

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Which column is the zip code column?

Comment: There are about 50 lines and the line i gave you is a sample. Im just trying to return a result that only displays lines that have the digits 4,5,6,7 and 9 in it. The last column is zipcode as referenced above. In the zipcode only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you meant "How do I use grep to..."

If all of the lines in the file have a 5 digit zip at the end of each line, then:

egrep "[45679]{5}$" filename

Should give you what you want.

If there might be whitespace between the zip and the end of the line, then:

egrep "[45679]{5}[[:space:]]*$" filename

would be more robust.

If the problem is more general than that, please describe it more accurately.

Comment: There are about 50 lines and the line i gave you is a sample. Im just trying to return a result that only displays lines that have the digits 4,5,6,7 and 9 in it. The last column is zipcode as referenced above. In the zipcode only –

Answer (score 0):

Following regex should fetch you desired result:

```
egrep "[45679]+$" file
```

Answer (score 0):

If by "grep" you mean, "the correct tool", then the solution you seek is:

```
awk '$7 ~ /^[45679]*$/' input
```

This will print all lines of input in which the 7th field consists only of the characters 4,5,6,7, and 9.  If you want to specify 'the last column' rather than the 7th, try

```
awk '$NF ~ /^[45679]*$/' input
```